# Sql Server Any data from the row itself with Try Catch?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Using Try/Catch with SqlServer 2008R2, is there a trick to getting some information out of the row that caused the error?  For example,

```
    BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO MyTable
        SELECT * 
        FROM @MyTableVar
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- In here, is there some way to know, for example, MyTable.SomeColumn for the offending row?
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
DECLARE @MyResults TABLE (
Id INT IDENTITY( 1, 1 )
TheKey VARCHAR(20),
Success BIT
)

-- Initially set Success to 1 for all rows
INSERT INTO @MyResults
    SELECT TheKey, 1
    FROM @MyTableVar

DECLARE @CurrentKey VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @CurrentId INT

DECLARE incoming CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, TheKey FROM @MyResults

OPEN incoming
FETCH incoming into @Id, @CurrentKey
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY   
        INSERT INTO OfficialTable
            SELECT * 
            FROM @MyTableVar TV
            WHERE TV.TheKey = @CurrentKey
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
                    -- On any failure, update the proper row in @MyResults
        UPDATE @MyResults 
        SET Success = 0
        WHERE TheKey = @CurrentKey AND Id = @CurrentId
    END CATCH           
    FETCH NEXT FROM incoming INTO @Id, @CurrentKey
END
CLOSE incoming

SELECT * FROM @MyResults
```

In the CATCH, I know the key to @MyTableVar, so, I should be able to look up anything I need with that.